# Adjectives between "plain" and "good" that can be used before a noun

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I want to complete the following sentence.

> Thirty years ago, a person with a bachelor's degree could get a good job after graduation. However, people living in the 21st century can only get a ____ job with a bachelor's degree.

I want to use an adjective that is less positive than "good" in the blank. "plain" means "neither good and nor bad" I think. I want to find a word(preferably a formal one) that means "slightly good".

Comment: 'OK'? 'OK-_ish_'? 'good-_ish_'?

Comment: @Keepthesemind Is there a more formal one that can be used in written English?

Comment: Sure, '(merely or minimally) acceptable', '(minimally or barely) satisfactory'.

Comment: How about *mediocre*?  (although I disagree with the intent of the sentence completely. It all depends on the degree. There are many great jobs to be had today in engineering with a BS)

Comment: I think you're trying to split hairs a bit too much.

Comment: *ho-hum* is fairly common in this context.

Answer (score 4):

**"a fair job"** may fit.  Neither good nor bad, just satisfactory.

> - fair - (adj) adequate - [**MW**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fair)
> - fair - moderately or tolerably good -  [**D.com**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fair)

"a fair understanding of the work"

"They gave only a fair performance of the play"

Comment: or satisfactory itself.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [***adequate***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adequate) may do.

> Satisfactory or acceptable in quality or quantity.
> *‘this office is perfectly adequate for my needs’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adequate

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like slightly better than an *ordinary/plain/average* job, perhaps a ***decent/passable*** one.

M-W:

> **[decent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decent)**
> *adjective*
> 4 :  fairly good :  adequate, satisfactory : ***decent** wages*
>
> Are there any decent schools in that area?
> I've got to get some
> decent clothes.
>
> **[passable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passable)**
> *adjective*
> : good enough : adequate or satisfactory
>
> He did a passable job with the assignment.
>
> **[ordinary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ordinary)**
> *adjective*
> : normal or usual : not unusual, different, or special
>
> : neither very good nor very bad :**not very impressive**
>
> The meal was ordinary and uninspired

Comment: But isn't ordinary=plain in this setting?

Comment: @TiWen, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about **run-of-the-mill**, **average**, or **mediocre**?

> Thirty years ago, a person with a bachelor's degree could get a good
> job after graduation. However, people living in the 21st century can
> only get a **run-of-the-mill** job with a bachelor's degree.
>
> Thirty years ago, a person with a bachelor's degree could get a good
> job after graduation. However, people living in the 21st century can
> only get an **average** job with a bachelor's degree.
>
> Thirty years ago, a person with a bachelor's degree could get a good
> job after graduation. However, people living in the 21st century can
> only get a **mediocre** job with a bachelor's degree.

From Dictionary.com:

> [**run-of-the-mill**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/run-of-the-mill): merely average; commonplace; mediocre
>
> [**average**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/average?s=t): typical;
> common; ordinary
>
> [**mediocre**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mediocre?s=t): of only
> ordinary or moderate quality; neither good nor bad; barely adequate

Each of these words is less positive than *good* without being *bad*.

Answer (score -1):

A reasonable [see meaning 2 here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reasonable) job is one which is better than many people have in terms of stimulation, responsibilities, status and pay but does not convey high status and is not likely to make the holder rich, at least not without many promotions.

Comment: Your answer should be self-contained.